# im$M = $im$MM^t$ for any matrix $M$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can I show the statement? Actually I proved that $\ker M = \ker M^t M$, by usual inner product argument that if $v \in \ker M^t M$, then $0 = <M^t M v, v> = <Mv , Mv> $ so $Mv = 0$.

Therefore, im $M = $im $M^t M$ from the dimension theorem. But, I don't know how to prove that im $M^t M =$im $M M^t$. Could you give some hint?

Comment: I think you mean $\text{rank }M = \text{rank }M^tM$. Because in general it doesn't even make sense for $\text{im }M$ to equal $\text{im }M^tM$, because, as linear transformations, $M$ and $M^tM$ don't even necessarily have the same codomain.

Comment: @BrentKerby Oh yes, actually M is square matrix.

Comment: The thing you're trying to prove is false, though, even for square matrices. For instance, take $M=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $MM^t=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ whereas $M^tM=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, and these do not have the same image. If you replace im by rank, though, then it is true.

Comment: The rank-nullity theorem (which is what I assume you mean by "dimension theorem") only gives you $\text{dim}(\text{im }M) = \text{dim}(\text{im } M^tM)$, i.e., $\text{rank }M = \text{rank }M^tM$, not $\text{im } M = \text{im } M^tM$.

Comment: @BrentKerby Oh I see.. Now I understand what you point out...

Comment: @BrentKerby But I think guestDiego 's answer seems right, what's wrong with his proof?

Comment: @BrentKerby But in general, we can decompose finite dimensional vector space $V$ as im $L \oplus \ker L$ for any linear operator, right?

Comment: The proof started with the premise that $\text{im}(M^tM)=\text{im}(M)$, which is not correct.

Comment: Also, the decomposition $V=\text{im }L\oplus\text{ker }L$ is not right. It is true, however, that $V=\text{im }L^t\oplus\text{ker }L$, and also $\text{im}(M^tM)=\text{im}(M^t)$.

Comment: @BrentKerby The last statement you say, are What I want to prove. Do you give me some hint for im$(M^t M) =$ im $(M^t)$?

Comment: Prove containment holds one direction, and then compare dimensions to show the containment is an equality.

Comment: So, I actually assumed that the statement $ \text{im}(M^tM)=\text{im}(M)$ was correct. Since it is not and it is not true that $\text{im}(M^tM)=\text{im}(M M^t)$ I erase my answer. Thanks to the help of Brent Kerby

Comment: @BrentKerby Thank you for your help. I completed the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use the fact that $\text{rank }M = \text{rank }M^t$, which is true because column rank equals row rank.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my question on my own. First of all, from ker$M=$ker$M^t M$, rk$M$ =rk$M^t M$ = rk$M^t$. Now apply above ker$M=$ker$M^t M$ statement by replacing $M$ with $M^t$, we can get  rk$M^t$ =rk$(M^t)^t M^t$ = rk$MM^t$ = rk$M^t$. Since im$M$ contain im$MM^t$ trivially and their rank is equivalent, so that we can conclude im$M$ = im$MM^t$. Thank you.